# Ubuntu Laptop Install

Tags: system-installation

I have a installation disc for Ubuntu and I put it in. My result is shown by the attached picture.  It says to reboot my computer with the disc inside the laptop to run Ubuntu.  However it does not do anything, my computer is exactly the same as it was before. No prompts come up, by desktop is the same as if i never touched the disc to begin with. I have been working with this for 12 hours and I'm about to kill myself with the computer by smashing it over my head.

[image]

Comment: You can upload the picture somewhere like http://postimage.org/ or https://imgur.com/, then add a link to it to your post and someone with sufficient rep can review and add it for you. I recommend also explaining specifically what happened when it *did not let you progress*. Did it freeze? Was there an error message? A more detailed description, together with the picture, may make it possible to answer this. You can [edit] your post to add this and any other relevant information.

Comment: Also, why are you suing such an old version of Ubuntu? Any computer capable of running Windows 7 (like yours) should be able to run at least Ubuntu 10.04, probably newer.

Comment: Plus I'm sorry but the fact that you are asking for help on something about an unsupported release turns the question automatically off-topic

Answer (score 1):

You may have to configure your laptop's BIOS to boot off the CD.  Restart your computer and watch closely for a brief message that tells you which key to press for 'startup options', 'system configuration', or something similar.  Once you have determined which key to press, enter the BIOS and set the boot priority to try the CD first.  Unfortunately BIOSs vary wildly so I cannot give you exact steps.